# Linear Algebra - Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I am a little stuck with the idea of subspaces in Linear Algebra.

The Theorem states the following:

> If W is a set of one or more vectors in a vector space V, then W is a subspace
>       of V if and only if the following conditions hold.
>
> (a) If **u** and **v** are vectors in W, then **u+v** is in W.
>
> (b) If k is any scalar and **u** is any vector in W, then k **u** is in W.

In words, this Theorem states that W is a subspace of V if and only if it is closed under
addition and scalar multiplication.

So now comes the problem:
Determine if the following are subspaces in R3

```
1) All vectors of the form (a, 0, 0)

2) All vectors of the form (a, 1, 1)
```

If I would take #1 and do the zero vector test:
Then (0,0,0)*(a,0,0) = pass

If I would do addition or part (a) of the Theorem then (a1, 0, 0) + (a2, 0, 0) = (a1+a2, 0, 0)

And even for part (b) c(a, 0, 0) = (ac, 0, 0) pass

So it would be a subspace in R3. But why would #2 not be a subspace in R3?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W$ consist of all vectors of the form $(a_1, 1, 1)$. That is, $\;W = \{(a, 1, 1)\mid a \in \mathbb R\}$.

$W$ defines a *subset* of $\mathbb R^3$. We can not call $W$ a *subspace* of $\mathbb R^3$ unless we can prove it is closed under $(1)$ vector addition ***and*** it is closed under $(2)$ scalar multiplication.

**Prompts**:

$(1)$ Evaluate $(a_1, 1, 1) + (a_2, 1, 1)$. Is the sum in $W$?

$(2)$ Or, alternatively, is $\;\;c(a_1, 1, 1) = (ca_1, c, c) \in W\,$ for $\,c \neq 1\,$?

Comment: Well that would evaluate (a1+a2, 2, 2).. But what should this tell me, so I would be able to define if it is a subspace... Why would the sum or product not be a subspace anymore?

Comment: Because $W$ consists only of vectors of the form $(a, 1, 1)$, so $W$ is not closed under vector addition (since the sum of two vectors in W is not again, in $W$), nor is it closed under scalar multiplication (since when multiplied by a scalar not equal to $1$, the result is not a vector in W).

Comment: Thank you, for this detailed answer... :)

Comment: You're welcome, djcrackhome!